# How to foreach much objects in array - jquery?

Tags: jquery, arrays, object, each

In PHP file, I have the following concept:

```
// return assoc
$res = DBQUERY;
foreach ($res as $key => $value) {
$retval[$cnt] = array("id_enumeration" => $key, "display_value" => $value);
$cnt++;
}
echo json_encode($retval);
```

In success result I got in Firebug **array of objects** like this:

> > [
> >     {"id_enumeration": 3602, "display_value": "Test1"}, 
> >     {"id_enumeration": 3604, "display_value": "Test2"}, 
> >     {"id_enumeration": 3605, "display_value": "Test3"}, 
> >     {"id_enumeration": 3607, "display_value": "Test4"}, 
> >     {"id_enumeration": 3610, "display_value": "Test5"}
> >     ]

I'm trying to perform this code by foreaching:

```
success: function(data) {
   // get array:
   $.each(data, function(idx, obj) { 
      // get each object:
      $.each(obj, function(key, value) {    
         console.log("Display value: " + value.display_value + " ID enumeration: " + value.id_enumeration);                             
      });
   });
}
```

But variables in console.log are **undefined**. How to each much objects in array? What is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have `obj` which is an array of objects which has the `display_value` property, so you can access it via `obj.display_value` in the first `$.each()` loop, there is no need for the second one

```
   $.each(data, function(idx, obj) { 
      console.log("Display value: " + obj.display_value + " ID enumeration: " + obj.id_enumeration);                             
   });
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/8JGPw/)

Comment: `$.each(data, function(idx, obj) {          console.log("Display value: " + obj.display_value + " ID enumeration: " + obj.id_enumeration);                             
});`

Still undefined.

Comment: Works now... My mistake, forgotten dataType: "json".